# How to create exe using VS 2013 for working Windows XP and Above?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-xp

I am created a exe using VisualStudio 2013. That exe works in both Win7 and Win8 perfectly. But it not works in win XP. when I run the exe it end suddenly.
[image: Setup Image]

Comment: **1)** is the build is for x64? if it does- it won't work - xp supports is 32bit (x86) only  **2)** you maybe using .net 3.5 or above which need to be insatlled on win xp.. try to downgrade and compile your code to .net v2

Comment: thnks Ymz for your comment.
1) no I build for both x64 and x86 (bulid with Any CPU).

Comment: How about your .Net framework target, as ymz suggested? I'm willing to bet that's the problem. Windows XP doesn't support anything newer than .Net framework 4.0, and your default is most likely 4.5, which is supported only on Vista and newer.

Comment: 2) I can't downgrade to .net v2. Earlier I build the setup with framework 4 VS 2010 and it works properly in XP. I convert it to 2013.

Comment: thanks Spline,
I use framework .net v4.o

Comment: I installed the my setup in win 7 machine.Then I copied the installed files from win7, paste it in XP machine and ran. It works. The problem is not of my framework. I think its about my Setup build project solution. I download it from this link [https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d]